# What is needed for referencing custom module?

Tags: angularjs, module

I cannot find example which shows the last step of building/using custom module -- referencing it in code. Let's say I have such line in my custom module:

```
angular.module('shared', []).factory('Factory', [Module]);
```

Then in my main app, I declared the dependency:

```
let app = angular.module('admin',[
  "shared",
]);
```

So far, so good. The question is how do I access this `shared`? In my case it is `undefined`. What do I miss?

Comment: How u accessing it can u please share the script

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN, for now I simply checking if it is working, so I write `console.log(shared)` right under this `let app...` line. Just in case I added `console.log` in main controller, still `undefined`. For other modules (like `datime`) all I needed to do was point out dependency, so I am puzzled what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now inject elements in admin module that are registered in shared, like factories, controllers, providers, directives etc.

So you can inject Factory to some factory in your admin module.

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to make in reverse, i.e. to point out in my custom module what should be automatically injected? Two reasons for that, in Node.js you point out what is exported, and when you import it you have it, secondly I didn't inject anything for other modules, like `datime` I simply added it to dependencies.

Comment: Everything that you register in shared is available if you inject shared in your module, but you still need to inject everything (e.g. factories) in the elements that uses your module elements..

If admin module has a controller that needs to use Factory, you need to inject module Shared in module Admin, as well as inject Factory in the controller.

So no, you can't do this the other way around.

Comment: For clarity, you can call your module with angular.module("modulename"), but you only need that to register new elements to the module

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I understand the sense of the trick `datetime` uses -- it names the entire module with the same name as main factory method, so it is `datetime` all the time. Now the only missing piece to make it really nice is to reference factory method (which produces object) as the object itself. So both Node.js and angular sides (it is shared code) would have the same syntax.